# Make {dashes} and {comma} synonyms of {punctuation}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At the moment, there are 142 questions tagged with [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation), 26 questions tagged with [dashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dashes) (4 of them also featuring [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation)) and 9 questions tagged with [comma](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma) (5 of them also featuring [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation)). As [dashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dashes) and [comma](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma) seem to be just special cases of [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation), I suggest that the former tags should be made synonyms of [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) and that the existing questions/answers should be merged.

Comment: Do commas as decimal markers count as punctuation?

Comment: @doncherry I'd say yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As my proposal gained a score larger than +10, I ask a moderator to implement it, i.e., to make [dashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dashes) and [comma](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma) synonyms of [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) and to merge the existing questions/answers.

Comment: I now merged the two tags to [tag:punctuation] and made them synonyms.